# Under ColumnDef cellEditorParams values are not updating with recent data values - ag-grid Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using cellEditorParams in column Definitions and for values while initialising column definitions there is no data so as it is showing empty but after one service call I'm getting data for values filed, but view is not updating according to the recent data. When i switch in between tabs and come back and check here my component is reinitialising and this time i can see data got updated.

this is how i defined column definitions:

```js
  serviceObj: string[] = [];
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.myService.readCalls.subscribe(readCal => {
    this.serviceObj = readCal;
  })
 }
  
// Defining the Columns
  createColumnDefs() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Header 1', field: 'header1',
        headerTooltip: '',
        width: 250,
        menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
        filterParams: {
          clearButton: true
        },
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
          required: true,
          values: this.serviceObj
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Header 2', field: 'header2',
        headerTooltip: '',
        width: 200,
        menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
        filterParams: {
          clearButton: true
        },
        editable: true
      }
     }
   ]
```

Here serviceObj variable is getting values after initialising the column definitions but grid is not updating with recent values. So is there any way to handle this scenario or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: A few lines under the first `cellEditorParams`, you seem to have an extra closing bracket (}). Is that a typo in the snippet?

Comment: @rateLess Yeah that is typo and corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality working fine with few minor changes to assign cellEditorParams but I'm not sure how that changes are working in depth. But it's working with following changes.

```js
serviceObj: string[] = [];
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.myService.readCalls.subscribe(readCal => {
    this.serviceObj = readCal;
  })
 }
  
 private getValArray() {
  return {
      values: this.serviceObj
  };
}
 
// Defining the Columns
  createColumnDefs() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Header 1', field: 'header1',
        headerTooltip: '',
        width: 250,
        menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
        filterParams: {
          clearButton: true
        },
        editable: true,
        cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: this.getValArray.bind(this)
      }
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Header 2', field: 'header2',
        headerTooltip: '',
        width: 200,
        menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
        filterParams: {
          clearButton: true
        },
        editable: true
      }
     }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuu need to wait untill readCalls promise resolve. basically set column defination after promise resolve.

```
this.myService.readCalls.subscribe(readCal => {
this.serviceObj = readCal;
this.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs()
})
createColumnDefs() {
return [
  {
    headerName: 'Header 1', field: 'header1',
    headerTooltip: '',
    width: 250,
    menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
    filterParams: {
      clearButton: true
    },
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: this.getValArray.bind(this)
  }
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Header 2', field: 'header2',
    headerTooltip: '',
    width: 200,
    menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab'],
    filterParams: {
      clearButton: true
    },
    editable: true
  }
 }
 ]
```